# How to Get the Max Daily Value per Week by Grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am making a project which requires me to first calculate how much distance was traveled per day. and then on that data I have to how show What was the maximum, minimum and average distance traveled that particular week?
This is a mongoDB script I have written.

```
db = connect("localhost:27017/mydb");
var result = db.trips.aggregate([
{
    "$unwind" : "$trips"
},
{
    "$match" : {
        "trips.startTime" : {"$lte" : ISODate("2015-10-31T23:59:59Z"), "$gte" : ISODate("2015-10-25T00:00:00Z")}
    }
},
{
    "$group" :
    {
        "_id" : {
            "date" : {"$dayOfMonth" : "$trips.startTime"}
        },
        "distance" :{"$sum" : "$trips.distance"}
    }
}
]);
while(result.hasNext())
{
    print(tojson(result.next()));
}
```

Which when replaced by dynamic dates gives me correct values. 
Now it leaves me with two options, either I modify the current group query or write a double group query. Double group query seems a more valid approach. My attempt at writing such a query.

```
{
    "$group" :
    {
        "_id" : { 
            "week" : "$_id.date" 
        },
        "max-distance" : {
            "$max" : "$distance"
        }
    }
}
```

Adding these lines didn't make a difference, clearly I know I am doing wrong, but how to correct it. i would need help with that
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to wan the [`$week`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/) operator, but of course you need a valid `Date` as input in order to extract the "week" from that.

What you may not know is that you can instead use "date math" to round out the date to a "day", where the result is still a `Date` object. Then you can use the `$week` operator to obtain your `$max` values:

```js
db.trips.aggregate([
    { "$unwind" : "$trips" },
    { "$match": {
        "trips.startTime" : {
            "$lte": ISODate("2015-10-31T23:59:59Z"), 
            "$gte": ISODate("2015-10-25T00:00:00Z")
        }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "$add": [
                { "$subtract": [
                    { "$subtract": [ "$trips.startTime", new Date(0) ] },
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$subtract": [ "$trips.startTime", new Date(0) ] },
                        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                    ]}
                ]},
                new Date(0)
            ]
        },
        "distance": { "$sum": "$trips.distance" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {  "$week": "$_id" },
        "max-distance": { "$max": "$distance" }   
    }
]);
```

The basic trick in the first part is when you [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) one `Date` object from another, the result is the millseconds in difference. So using the epoch date the data is converted to it's milliseconds equivalent and then you can use the math to round that number to a day.

`(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)` is the number of milliseconds in a day, so finding the modulo ( [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) ) of that returns the remainder of milleseconds past the day, which you can subtract from the date value in the document to round to a day.

The same is true of `$add` when adding a `Date` object to a number, the result is a `Date`. So this handles the conversion, and then the `$week` can be extracted from there.

Comment: Well I did not need to calculate the week startDate as it was available in my node program. I usually test my db calls before I put them in node but the learning on how to calculate a startdate of week was really helpful. Thanks for a wonderful explanation. I wish I could upvote more.

Comment: @SarasArya Your `$match` selection presently only selects one week of data, so the real point here is that you can expand that selection to multiple weeks and the same code will aggregate the values for each week present in the sample. Handy to know this if your intent now or later was to produce a graph of this data or otherwise look at multiple weeks results at a glance, without performing multiple queries.

Comment: The intent is actually to show a graph. But the weeks are tightly coupled. Only those weeks need to shown for which data exists. So I calculate this data(for which weeks I need to show the graph) in one function which actually goes to frontend to generate that many slider graph windows and I call on another function to fetch the exact data. I don't know if there is a better method to do it. But thanks for the heads up I will look into it.

Comment: @SarasArya There is a better way and that is the answer I gave you. Expand the date selection to more than one week and see the results yourself.